# User logout (and sometimes login) doesn't work on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, backend

I need help with an issue I'm having with user login/logout on my production server.

Some background info:

- My backend for vercel production server is on render.com
- I have no problems with localhost, only on my test production server.
- Register/Login/Logout issues only happen with Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Brave. I have no issues on Firefox. I have not tested Safari yet.

Browser issues:

- On Chrome, Edge, (normal + private), and Brave (normal + private), I can log in/register but can't log out. No console errors.
- On Chrome Incognito, I can't even log in/register. No console errors.
- On Firefox (normal + private), it works as intended.

Relevant code:

```
//Relevant User Controllers

exports.registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password, passwordVerify } = req.body;

        console.log(req.body);

    
        if (!username || !password || !passwordVerify) {
            console.log("Check if all fields are present");
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ errorMessage: 'Please enter all required fields.' });
        }
    
        if (password.length < 6) {
            console.log("Check if the password isn't too short");
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({
                    errorMessage: 'Please enter a password of at least 6 characters.',
                });
        }
    
    
        if (password !== passwordVerify)
        {
            console.log("Check if the passwords are the same");
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ errorMessage: 'Please make sure the passwords match.' });
        }
    
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username: username });
        if (existingUser) {
            console.log("Check if a User already exists");
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({
                    errorMessage: 'An account with this username already exists.',
                });
        }

    
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        console.log("Password Hash: ", passwordHash)
    
        const newUser = await User.create({
            username,
            passwordHash,
        });

        console.log("Created new user")
    

        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                user: newUser.id,
            },
            process.env.JWT_SECRET
        );

        console.log("Signed the token")
    
        // Send the token in an HTTP-only cookie
        // Send the token in an HTTP-only cookie and redirect
        res.cookie('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? 'None' : 'Lax',
        })
        .end();


        console.log("Sent the token")

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("The error is: ", error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
}

exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
  
      if (!username || !password)
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errorMessage: 'Please enter all required fields.' });
  
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
      if (!existingUser)
        return res
          .status(401)
          .json({ errorMessage: 'Wrong username or password.' });
  
      const passwordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
        password,
        existingUser.passwordHash
      );
      if (!passwordCorrect)
        return res
          .status(401)
          .json({ errorMessage: 'Wrong username or password.' });
  
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          user: existingUser.id,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: '6h',
        }
      );
  
      res
        .cookie('token', token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
          sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? 'None' : 'Lax',
        })
        .send();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send();
    }
};


  exports.logoutUser = (req, res) => {
    res
      .clearCookie('token')
      .send();
  };
```

```
// relevant index.js code

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`));

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://[sitename hidden for privacy].vercel.app"],
  credentials: true,
}));



//MongoDB connection, routes, etc
...
...
```

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "blahblahblah": "6.9.420"
  }
}
```

Here's the hastebins for the code as well, if you prefer viewing it there:

- UserController: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ahamuzemek.php
- package.json: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ugayabazit.prolog
- index.js: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ivofegahax.php

In UserController, my NODE_ENV is set to production, not development, as I am testing it on the production server.

I suspect that this bit of code is causing the issues:

```
res
        .cookie('token', token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
          sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? 'None' : 'Lax',
        })
        .send();
```

But I've seen some threads on here talking about how playing around with this line:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));`
affected things too, but I don't think this is causing the issue--I could be wrong.

I've attached my package.json just in case my scripts are bad, but I doubt it:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated. Earlier, I wasn't able to log in at all, since I had this:

```
res
        .cookie('token', token, {
          httpOnly: true,
        })
        .send();
```

so when I added the secure and sameSite attributes, I was able to log in (aisde from Chrome Incognito), but logging out is broken now. Any help would be appreciated. Cookies are the bane of my existence.

And, if possible, please explain to me why things work on Firefox but nowhere else